# Image is not Inserting in MySQL. Error 1048

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing error(in arrow (2)) while executing query( in arrow(1)) and also unable to view image. Name path and spelling of image location is correct.

Screen shot of query output

[image]

Comment: _If the file doesn’t exist, NULL is returned:_ Are you sure the path is correct

Comment: _Other reasons for NULL_ **1)** The file must be located on the server host.
 **2)** You must have the FILE privilege in order to read the file. A user who has the FILE privilege can read any file on the server host that is either world-readable or readable by the MySQL server.
**3)** The file must be readable by all and its size less than max_allowed_packet bytes.

Comment: **4)** If the `secure_file_priv` system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory. ___This is quite likely your issue___

Comment: How to locate file on server host. What is secure_file_priv and how to set this. Please help me.

Comment: Please run the query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';` and show us the result

Comment: output= C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the result of

```
load_file('C:/hr.jpg')
```

results in `null`. You will probably need to fix the path to

```
load_file('C:\\hr.jpg')
```

Comment: @JaitavyaMishra where is the hr.jpg file in your filesystem?

Comment: location= C:\hr.jpg     I am working on my college project pls help me and pls suggest some other solution if possible.

Comment: @JaitavyaMishra then try with load_file('C:\\hr.jpg')

Comment: @JaitavyaMishra do you have access right to the file with the user that is running Oracle?

Comment: Problem is solved. First upload image in Uploads folder of mysql and then executing this query.                                                                                                     insert into display value (1,load_file('C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/shiv1.jpg'));

Comment: @JaitavyaMishra the file either did not exist in the location you specified, or the user you have worked with did not have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Execute following query. This will show path where you have to upload image.

> select @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;

*Result:* C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\                  [In my case]

**Step 2:** Upload image in Uploads folder.

**Step 3:** Execute query

> create table display (SR_no int,picture longblob not null  ) ;

We can user either blob or long blob for image.

> insert into display value (1,load_file('C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/shiv1.jpg'));

**Step 4:** Image will insert successfully.

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD_DATA` only works for files located in the same host as the MySQL server. In your case, I guess the MySQL server is remote.

To load data from a local file to a remote server, you need to use [LOAD DATA LOCAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) instead.

Comment: load_file() also work. Check my answer for same question. Tnx for help